# Django TastyPie 0.10.0 not accepting POST request

Tags: django, tastypie

I can't seem to get TastyPie to accept a POST request, made via Ajax or not. I get an error:

> The format indicated 'multipart/form-data' had no available
>   deserialization method. Please check your `formats` and
>   `content_types` on your Serializer.

My model resource is:

```
class ClippedCouponResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = ClippedCoupon.objects.all()
        allowed_methods = ['get', 'post']
        serializers = UrlencodeSerializer()
        authentication = DjangoCookieBasicAuthentication()
        authorization = DjangoAuthorization()
        default_format = 'application/json'
```

My serializer is:

```
from urlparse import urlparse

from tastypie.serializers import Serializer


class UrlencodeSerializer(Serializer):
    formats = ['json', 'jsonp', 'xml', 'yaml', 'html', 'plist', 'urlencode']
    content_types = {
        'json': 'application/json',
        'jsonp': 'text/javascript',
        'xml': 'application/xml',
        'yaml': 'text/yaml',
        'html': 'text/html',
        'plist': 'application/x-plist',
        'urlencode': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    }

    def from_urlencode(self, data, options=None):
        """ handles basic formencoded url posts """
        qs = dict((k, v if len(v) > 1 else v[0])
            for k, v in urlparse.parse_qs(data).iteritems())
        return qs

    def to_urlencode(self,content):
        pass
```

Right now, I'm just in local development mode, so all requests are going to `localhost:8000`, so I haven't enabled any cross-domain posting middleware. I'm able to execute a GET request to the endpoint, `/v2/api/clippedcoupon/` just fine, but a POST utterly fails. I'm using POSTMAN in Chrome to test. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

I implemented [cookie based authentication for TastyPie](https://github.com/amezcua/TastyPie-DjangoCookie-Auth/blob/master/DjangoCookieAuth.py) and everything is working as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add Following in MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES in your settings.py file

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'mysite.crossdomainxhr.XsSharing'
)

Copy this file and put it in same level as settings.py

- crossdomainxhr.py

from django import http

try:
    from django.conf import settings
    XS_SHARING_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = settings.XS_SHARING_ALLOWED_ORIGINS
    XS_SHARING_ALLOWED_METHODS = settings.XS_SHARING_ALLOWED_METHODS
    XS_SHARING_ALLOWED_HEADERS = settings.XS_SHARING_ALLOWED_HEADERS
    XS_SHARING_ALLOWED_CREDENTIALS = settings.XS_SHARING_ALLOWED_CREDENTIALS
except AttributeError:
    XS_SHARING_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = '*'
    XS_SHARING_ALLOWED_METHODS = ['POST', 'GET', 'OPTIONS', 'PUT', 'DELETE', 'PATCH']
    XS_SHARING_ALLOWED_HEADERS = ['Content-Type', '*']
    XS_SHARING_ALLOWED_CREDENTIALS = 'true'

class XsSharing(object):
    """
    This middleware allows cross-domain XHR using the html5 postMessage API.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://foo.example
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE

Based off https://gist.github.com/426829
"""
def process_request(self, request):
    if 'HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD' in request.META:
        response = http.HttpResponse()
        response['Access-Control-Allow-Origin']  = XS_SHARING_ALLOWED_ORIGINS
        response['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = ",".join( XS_SHARING_ALLOWED_METHODS )
        response['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = ",".join( XS_SHARING_ALLOWED_HEADERS )
        response['Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'] = XS_SHARING_ALLOWED_CREDENTIALS
        return response

    return None

def process_response(self, request, response):
    response['Access-Control-Allow-Origin']  = XS_SHARING_ALLOWED_ORIGINS
    response['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = ",".join( XS_SHARING_ALLOWED_METHODS )
    response['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = ",".join( XS_SHARING_ALLOWED_HEADERS )
    response['Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'] = XS_SHARING_ALLOWED_CREDENTIALS

    return response
```

this will help

Comment: Unfortunately, I get the same error. Here's the full traceback: https://gist.github.com/btaylordesign/6885415/raw/29f167760a2fc2c3ec119b9ac1c0123e936b4b98/gistfile1.txt

Comment: @Brandon plz send me ur json Documnet that u r sending to POST your message shows that data is not properly formatted

Comment: It is simply: {'coupon_id': 1, 'user_id': 1}

Comment: @Brandon this is how i send my data to tastypie 

    data = JSON.stringify({"usergroup":"alok"})
    $.ajax({
         url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/salesreport/?format=json',
          type: 'POST',
          async: false,
          contentType: 'application/json',
          data: data,
          dataType: 'json',
          processData: false,
          success: function(data){
          alert("Done!")
          },
         })

Comment: OK, now I'm getting a 401 from the endpoint, so getting closer. It was the format of the JSON that I was sending.

Comment: Looks like I just need to add a CSRF token.

Comment: @Brandon try that also. and put JSON.stringify before your data

Comment: WooHoo! I got it to work by implementing a custom, cookie based authentication, and I had forgotten to add authorization to the Resource.